# ERROR 1: None of ECW_ENCODE_KEY and ECW_ENCODE_COMPANY were provided

Tags: ubuntu, sdk, format, gdal

I downloaded ERDAS-ECW_JPEG_2000_SDK-5.1.1 and tried to use it with GDAL to create ECW files from georeferenced PNG files, but they are not created, it basically complains about:

> ERROR 1: None of ECW_ENCODE_KEY and ECW_ENCODE_COMPANY were provided.

I thought it was free to do so with files smaller than 500 MB (mine is 50 MB). Here the full output:

```
+ gdalwarp -of ECW -t_srs EPSG:4326 -srcnodata 128 -dstalpha s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.png s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw
Creating output file that is 14185P x 14185L.
Processing input file s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.png.
Using band 4 of source image as alpha.
Copying nodata values from source s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.png to destination s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw.
ERROR 6: s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw, band 1: SetNoDataValue() not supported for this dataset.
ERROR 6: s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw, band 2: SetNoDataValue() not supported for this dataset.
ERROR 6: s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw, band 3: SetNoDataValue() not supported for this dataset.
0ERROR 1: None of ECW_ENCODE_KEY and ECW_ENCODE_COMPANY were provided.
Both are required.
ERROR 1: None of ECW_ENCODE_KEY and ECW_ENCODE_COMPANY were provided.
Both are required.
ERROR 1: None of ECW_ENCODE_KEY and ECW_ENCODE_COMPANY were provided.
Both are required.
ERROR 1: None of ECW_ENCODE_KEY and ECW_ENCODE_COMPANY were provided.
Both are required.
.ERROR 1: s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw, band 5: An error occured while writing a dirty block
ERROR 1: s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw, band 1: An error occured while writing a dirty block
ERROR 1: s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw, band 2: An error occured while writing a dirty block
ERROR 1: s05w85_200_200_F1_R3_z.ecw, band 3: An error occured while writing a dirty block
```

The only solution to get those keys is to buy that ERDAS software? again, I had the impression that it could be possible.

Any support is very welcomed,